# Redirection criticality at htaccess

Tags: php, asp.net, apache, .htaccess, unix

I have faced redirection criticality for one of my website .
Here is it --

I have to redirect http://local.port-all/antique/c-Furniture/m-Antique-Dining-Room-Tables.html
to http://local.port-all/antique-c-Furniture-m-Antique+Dining+Room+Tables.html

So I wrote htaccess redirect

```
    Redirect /antique/c-Furniture/m-Antique-Dining-Room-Tables.html /antique-c-Furniture-m-Antique+Dining+Room+Tables.html
```

So it redirects to specific url. But there is a default rule set for the site ,

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So when my redirection works, it adds *route* at the end of the redirected url. That means after redirection it shows

```
    http://local.port-all/antique-c-Furniture-m-Antique+Dining+Room+Tables.html?_route_=antique/c-Furniture/m-Antique-Dining-Room-Tables.html
```

But I need only

```
    http://local.port-all/antique-c-Furniture-m-Antique+Dining+Room+Tables.html
```

after redirection which I did not get. I can not delete

```
    _route_ from RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

as it created default route access of the site. So I need different solution.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can any expert can help? No response from expert !!!